# Font identification dificulties

Tags: font-identification

Can anyone tell me what this font is or which is similar?

[image: the] [image: of]

I'm really sorry I'm unable to provide more letters due "technical issues" and, as I've read in similar topics, answering anticipatedly, yes, I've cleaned the image, as best as I could (as I'm not a designer), as well as I've tried to identify by myself in WhatTheFont, FontSquirrel and "manually" in IdentiFont

Closest I've got was Arial, but although very similar in some letters, some didn't match.

Answer (score 14):

This is **[Eurostyle Ext2 Bold](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/eurostile/ext2-bold/)**

About identifying it. I did it successfully on WhatTheFont!, the issue I guess you are having is due to the blurriness of the font, or because you are trying to locate it with these images as is.

You must make the text clear for being analyzed by their engine, sometimes this requires you to give it a hand.

This is the picture I sent to be analysed:

[image]

Basically i just painted it black all around, then inverted colors, I also took a pixel pencil to make the sillouette of the "e" look clearer, so it would help out the algorythm.

Always try to have your text very clear when submitting to WhatTheFont!, it is a little myopic.